# PDF's downloaded from password protected url (requests package) can't be opened

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, python-requests

I'm trying to write a script to save pdf's locally via a password protected url. The file is saving to the local directory properly but an error message appears when trying to open the pdf (unsupported or damaged file).

Thoughts on possible solutions?

```
import requests

 r=requests.get('https://www.website.com/export-pdf',verify=False, auth=('user','pass'))
 with open('file_name.pdf, 'wb') as fd:
   for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
     fd.write(chunk)
```

Comment: did you bother doing any basic debugging, like LOOKING at the file you saved. does it have content (e.g. is not zero-bytes)? Did you open the file in a text/hex editor to see what's really in it? Maybe that site's serving up a html page saying "sorry, wrong username" or whatever.

Comment: I seemed to have skipped that step given that the link functions properly when run via a browser manually. It is in fact a zero-byte file. Could this simply be the site owner restricting access via scripts?

Comment: that or there's an http redirect that your code isn't "following", and redirects tend to have no "body", which is what you're writing out. no body, no data to write = zero-byte file.

Comment: got it. thanks for the help!